# HAX is working and emulator runs in fast virt mode in AVD , in Android Studio

Tags: android, windows, android-studio, virtual-device-manager

I got following error message when I attempt to start a emulator in Android Studio

```
emulator: WARNING: Crash service did not start
emulator: WARNING: Increasing RAM size to 1024MB
emulator: WARNING: VM heap size set below hardware specified minimum of 384MB
emulator: WARNING: Setting VM heap size to 384MB
Hax is enabled
Hax ram_size 0x40000000
HAX is working and emulator runs in fast virt mode.
qemu-system-i386.exe: -drive if=none,index=1,id=cache,file=C:\Users\user\.android\avd\Samsung_Galaxy_S6_edge_API_22.avd/cache.img: could not open disk image C:\Users\user\.android\avd\Samsung_Galaxy_S6_edge_API_22.avd/cache.img: Could not open 'C:\Users\user\.android\avd\Samsung_Galaxy_S6_edge_API_22.avd/cache.img': Invalid argument
```

Now I couldn't start an emulator . How could I fix this ?

Comment: Anybody know what `Hax ram_size 0x40000000` actually means? How big is that?

Answer (score 1):

1) check What is your Haxm Size  set it to greater Than 1024MB
2)  Reduce Avd Ram Size to 756MB

Try These Two Points ;

Comment: where would I find Haxm Size and Avd Ram Size? And yes I do have 64-bit architecture

Answer (score 0):

Installing HAXM with 756 RAM:

```
sudo $ANDROID_SDK/sdk/extras/intel/Hardware_Accelerated_Execution_Manager/silent_install.sh -u
sudo $ANDROID_SDK/sdk/extras/intel/Hardware_Accelerated_Execution_Manager/silent_install.sh -m 756
```